# Add input current value and sorting using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have jQuery function, with that I want to add current input value and sorting them accordingly. But my function not adding.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

$('input[type=button]').click(function(){

var val=$('input[type=text]').val();
var nn = $('.rhs').text(val);


})

})
</script>


<style>
.rhs { height:360px}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="click"/>
<div class="rhs"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DvCD4/1/

Comment: what do you mean by sorting again? can you elaborate your question?

Comment: working for me also http://jsfiddle.net/J5AZU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this: (***[the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jae5F/)***)

```
$(function(){
   var nn = [];
   $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
       nn.push($('input[type=text]').val());
       $('.rhs').html(nn.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}).join('<br>'));
   });
});
​
```

Comment: Your function adding value perfectly but did not sorting value

Comment: @amit Have you checked the demo, it sort the value.

Comment: yes i have check your code it is not sorting, add "a" then "b" then again "a"

Comment: @amit Yes, I assume your input is number, if you want to sort by string, then remove the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

ah i guess i got your point

```
    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
       var val = $('input[type=text]').val();
       var nn = $('.rhs').append(val+'<br/>');                
    });
```

Comment: adding values but not sorting values